# Better C# design to traverse file system asynchronously to process large number of files on daily basis

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, filesystems

I am creating a c# console application that will traverse through a given folder (and sub-folders) to encrypt all the files (binary or text) and update the `IsEncrypted` flag in the sqlserver database. There would be millions of files on client box that needs to encrypted. We are planning to run the application as scheduled task daily during off hours (say for 8 hours starting at 10 PM every night).

I have two options:

**Option 1**

File processing using `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
public void Process(ProcessorOptions options, ProcessorParameter parameter)
{
    int counter = 0;
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
    parallelOptions.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

    try
    {
        parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        if (options.NumberOfThreads > 0)
        {
            parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = options.NumberOfThreads;
        }

        if (options.StopTime != 0)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(callback => { cts.Cancel(); }, null, options.StopTime * 60000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        List<string> storagePaths = parameter.StoragePaths;
        Log("Process Started...");

        foreach (var path in storagePaths)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(TraverseDirectory(path, f => f.Extension != ".enc"), parallelOptions, file =>
            {
                if (file.Name.IndexOf("SRSCreate.dir") < 0)
                {
                    ProcessFile(parameter, file.FullName, file.Directory.Name, file.Name);
                    counter++;
                }
            });
        }
        Log(string.Format("Process Files Ended... Total File Count = {0}", counter));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        log.WriteWarningEntry(string.Format("Reached stop time = {0} min, explicit cancellation triggered. Total number of files processed = {1}", options.StopTime, counter.ToString()), ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        log.WriteErrorEntry(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I did benchmark it and found that it almost takes 7-8 minutes to process 2000 files. Is there something I could do to improve the performance? Also, what would be the best way to identify where to start in next run (next day)?

**Option 2**

Use existing design for `RabbitMQ` to push messages with file path to process the files for scalability purposes and for maintaining the list.

```
public void Process(ProcessorOptions options, ProcessorParameter parameter)
{
    try
    {
        using (IConnection connection = parameter.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                var queueName = parameter.TopicSubscription.DeriveQueueName();
                var queueDeclareResponse = channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
                EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

                consumer.Received += (o, e) =>
                {
                    string messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body);
                    FileData message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageContent, typeof(FileData)) as FileData;
                    ProcessFile(parameter, message.EntityId, message.Attributes["Id"], message.Attributes["filename"]);
                };

                string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.WriteErrorEntry(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        Trace.Exit(method);
    }
}
```

I still have to figure out how to stop reading the messages after the configured `StopTime`. Performance is not that great, i saw it takes approx 25 - 30 minutes to process 2000 files. We thought we can run multiple copies of the application either on one machine or multiple machines to process single queue to scale. Do you think, I can change this code to make it more optimal?

Final question: Do you think if there is some other option that is more efficient and scalable than above mentioned options?

Note:

1) The method `ProcessFile` calls encryption logic and the logic to update the database.

2) We traverse the folder and not start from database because, there are chances that there are files in file system that doesn't exist in database yet.

Comment: Most likely you'll hit tbe io limit of the box. First check the actual limiting component. Otherwise this is hard to answer. Oh, one question: what if your database gets out of sync? Would that be an major issue?

Comment: this question is a bit problematic as you are asking many things in one question....it all comes down to what the bottleneck is, what the disk is ( ssd?  are you writing back to the same drive? or different drives?).   You may be be better off with a single threaded reader, parallel encrypter, single threaded writer

Comment: @Stefan, These files are stored on server and they are viewed by client applications. The client application rely on the database to identify if the file needs to be decrypted to view or not based on IsEncrypted flag. So, database has to be in sync.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, I am sorry for asking so many questions in one post. I just want to keep everything in one place and I am sure this problem would help others too. I agree that sometimes you can do so much with the code, then you have to think about the hardware. That's the reason why we thought about RabbitMQ for scalability and if clients have hardware, they can throw more computers, disks (SSD) etc to double up on processing. Single threaded reader/writer won't choke up the system?

Comment: well, you need to maximize the disk throughput, hitting the disk from multiple threads may screw up any read / write caching of your disks.  I'd be doing a bunch of experiments to see.   I really don't see what you think rabbitmq is going to do for you.   But you haven't really described the deployment architecture at all.  From your question it seems    Disk -> Memory -> Encrypt -> Disk....    if encrypt is way more expensive than disk<->memory   and back to disk again, then using a distributed system for encryption might help.  But I'd probably use something like Akka for that.

Comment: Some questions. 1) How many physical drives are involved? 2) Are the encrypted files stored in the same filesystem with the unencrypted ones? 3) What percentage of files needs to be encrypted? 4) Does the encryption requires that the whole file is loaded on memory? 5) What is the average size of the files? 6) Is there a limit on the size of the files?

Comment: I agree that this will be disk intensive operation where everything is running on the app server - the encryption, DB updates, RabbitMQ etc. This is all existing design, I have no means to update any of these. If hardware is bottleneck, i am sure the clients can add more drives, ram etc. But, before getting there, i wanted to check if one option is better than other.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I am not sure how many physical drives will be involved in production. But client can add more if required. The unencrypted files are replaced with the encrypted file on the same server, 100% of the files needs to be encrypted as unencrypted files are the security risk and every day, the count will be going down. Yes, the encryption requires the file to be in memory for running the algorithm. The average size of the file ~3 mb. There is no limit on file size that i am aware of, but generally we get huge image files, word and excel doc and then some small text files.

Comment: voting to close as the problem has too many variables that aren't defined and depending on those variables there may be a number of different solutions, so given there is no real single answer to this question, and the comments have already highlighted the various things to consider, I'm marking this as "Too Broad"

Answer (score 1):

This goes into the territory of Performance Questions, so I will first link the Performance rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

This operation by it's very nature should be Diskbound, rather then CPU bound. How quickly the Process can iterate the files and how quickly it can read, encrypt and write the files - are all clearly Disk bound. And throwing more simultaneous operations at disks will make the slower, not faster. Unless of course you got some extreme setup like a Raid 0 of SSD's.

If there is anything that might benefit from Multitasking, it should be the DB access. Usually those go over the Network stack and especially if the DB is on another computer, there is a decent chance it will be slower then the disk. At the same time you do not want to spam the DB with queries. All queries have a overhead and 1 200-row query is faster then 200 1-row ones. So get the DB data in some form of enumeration or streaming approach, then iterate over the files. But which one will really be the slowest depends a bit on how many new/unencrypted files there are at every run.

It could be feasible to move this whole thing into the DB. There are 2 approaches to storing BLOBS with DB's and it sounds like you are using the "store on Disk, only link in DB". If so, attributes like Filestream might help you: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Slightly off Topic, but a Pet-Peeve of mine is Exception handling and you have a cardinal sin in your example code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.WriteErrorEntry(ex);
}
```

You catch `Exception` but do not let it go on, which mean you go on after fatal exceptions. That will only give you more - and less understandable - followup Exceptions. So you should never do that. There are two articles on exception handling that I do link a lot and I think they may help you here:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Good answer, but why did you have to start with [the rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant)? This is a case where performance is clearly a feature, not an afterthought.

Comment: I have read the rant. If you have to encrypt millions of files and you are scheduling daily tasks during off hours, then you have a performance problem to solve (and not much to rant about).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Please re-read part 2, 3 and 4. If you still need help to realize how it applies here, I can explain it to you in detail.

Comment: I wouldn't say no to a detailed explanation, since you offered to provide one, about how are applicable here the following points of @EricLippert's [rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/):
2) Do you really need to answer that question?
3) Is that really the bottleneck?
4) Is the difference relevant?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias 2) Deals with the question if there even **is** a problem that needs solving. If the code is already fast enough for the user, this work is just a pointless change with a lot of dangers and nothing to gain. The only possible Improovements anyone could think up was adding Multtiasking. And if you do that wrong, you end up with code that is more complex, more prone to error, needs more memory and is **slower** then what you started with. "don’t make performance-based changes unless you’ve identified a performance problem" | the op mentions no actuall problem.

Comment: 3) Points out that even if there is a problem, your asumption about the bottleneck is propably wrong. Multitasking only helps if waiting *is* the bottleneck. We have not yet established that there even is a problem, so the search for a bottleneck goes nowhere. "Use a profiler or other analysis tool to determine empirically where the bottleneck is before you start investigating alternatives"

Comment: 4) Points out that even if there is a problem and this is indeed the bottleneck, that might still not mater. If both are fast enough, this is just "Trivia with a high danger of Bugs". Wich also means Question 2 was never cleared. If neither is fast enough, this is again just "Trivia with a high danger of Bugs". This is not the droid you are looking for. You have to search somewhere else, hide the time it takes (via some basic background task), or just tell the user that he has to deal with this because that is the minimum time this will need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to analyze Eric Lippert's points, but you haven't actually answered how are these applicable here. The OP has millions of files to process, and with his current implementation he can process at maximum 15.000 files per hour. I bet my pet snake this is not what Eric Lippert had in mind when he wrote his [rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)! His motivation was probably some guy that was attempting to speed-up his database-heavy application by converting his `i++`s to `++i`s. 

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how many physical drives will be involved in production. But client can add more if required. The unencrypted files are replaced with the encrypted file on the same server, 100% of the files needs to be encrypted as unencrypted files are the security risk and every day, the count will be going down. Yes, the encryption requires the file to be in memory for running the algorithm. The average size of the file ~3 mb. There is no limit on file size that i am aware of, but generally we get huge image files, word and excel doc and then some small text files.

I can see that the problem has many unknowns, and this indicates that a single configuration will not cut it in all cases. So my suggestion is to make the system flexible. I would start by creating a configuration for the physical drives involved. Each physical drive should have a setting for concurrency. An SSD drive may work optimally with 2-3 threads concurrently reading or writing on it, while a hard disk drive could struggle with more than one. The next important setting would be the number of encrypter threads. Ideally the system should work best when the number of the running threads equals the numbers of available processors/cores of the machine. The flow of execution should look like this:

- The IO threads are reading or writing files from/to their associated physical drive.
- When a IO thread finishes reading an unencrypted file, it enqueues it in a global queue for processing.
- When a IO thread finishes writing an encrypted file, it also updates the database.
- The encrypter threads are constantly pooling the global queue for files to process.
- When an encrypter thread finishes processing a file, it enqueues it in the dedicated queue of the file's physical drive.
- When a IO thread becomes idle, it looks at the dedicated queue of its associated physical drive if there is any processed file. If there is, it dequeues it and writes it in the disk. If not, it continues by reading another file from the disk.

All this can be achieved by threads or tasks, and the [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class. No need for `Parallel.ForEach` or third party libraries.

Comment: I might have mis-read your question regarding number of physical drives. Do you mean number of physical drives where the unencrypted files reside? If yes, all the unencrypted files are stored in just one location in one drive. There is one folder and it is further organized by sub-folders named by 2 digit prefix of the document id. When you say global queue, are you referring to a physical queue like rabbitmq?

Comment: If all files are stored in just one drive then things are much simpler, but also the opportunities for performance improvements much diminished. The IO speed of the single drive will almost surely be the limiting factor (bottleneck) of the procedure. By queue I mean a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1), wrapped in a `BlockingCollection`. I don't really know anything about RabbitMQ to be honest.

Comment: Btw if the unencrypted files are stored in a different physical drive from the encrypted files, then there is immediately an opportunity for a x2 performance boost.